# OneDrive - Disable sync for one folder or file(s) inside synced parent folder

Tags: windows, windows-10, sync, onedrive

I'm running Win 10 and I have a folder which holds all my project I'm working on in one place. I also have this folder synced via OneDrive. 
But there's a problem. Inside some of those folders there's a folder, which holds configuration unique for every device. 
Is there any way, how to mark this children folder as 'do not sync and keep in PC' without disabling sync for the parent folder?

Example:

```
-- Projects (Synced)
   |-- Project1 (Synced)
       |-- files (Synced)
       |-- .conf (Not synced)
   |-- Project2 (Synced)
       |-- files (Synced)
       |-- .conf (Not synced)
```

Thank you.